# Map data via pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in long format. I want to convert it to wide format. Logic for column mapping - First column must have word 'bed', second column must have word 'm^2', third column must have word either 'floor' or 'lift'.

```
Type <- read.table(header = T, text = "
    Attributes
    '2 bed'
    '197 m²'
    'Floor 5 exterior with lift'
    '3 bed'
    'Ground floor exterior with lift'
    '3 bed'
    '110 m²'
    '195 m²'
    'Floor 5 exterior with lift'
    '3 bed'
    '110 m²'
    '5 bed'
    ")


Type2 <- Type %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Attributes, '^\\d+\\s*bed$'))) %>% 
  mutate(colnm = c('BedRoom', 'Size', 'Floor')[row_number()]) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = Attributes) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

**The above code doesnt work when 'bed' value is not available.**

**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: I hope the below solution works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to create an index for mapping each pattern specified in the post with `case_when/str_detect`.  Then, based on the index, we check for duplicate or the cases where the difference in adjacent index is less than or equal to 0 and create a group with cumulative sum of the logical vector.  Using the 'grp', we can directly convert the data into 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Type %>%
    mutate(ind = case_when(
             str_detect(Attributes, '\\bbed') ~ 1, 
             str_detect(Attributes, "m²$") ~ 2, 
             str_detect(Attributes, "\\b(Floor|lift)\\b")~ 3), 
         grp =  cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(ind) <= 0)),
    colnm =  c('BedRoom', 'Size', 'Floor')[ind]) %>% 
    select(-ind) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = Attributes) %>%     
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  BedRoom Size   Floor                          
#  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>                          
#1 2 bed   197 m² Floor 5 exterior with lift     
#2 3 bed   <NA>   Ground floor exterior with lift
#3 3 bed   110 m² <NA>                           
#4 <NA>    195 m² Floor 5 exterior with lift     
#5 3 bed   110 m² <NA>                           
#6 5 bed   <NA>   <NA>
```